# ggplot with customized font not showing properly on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, extrafont

I can customize the font in a `ggplot` with:

```
library(extrafont)

windowsFonts()
font_import(pattern = "comic", prompt = FALSE)
loadfonts(device = "win")
windowsFonts()

ggplot(mapping=aes(x=seq(1,10,.1), y=seq(1,10,.1))) + 
  geom_line(position="jitter", color="red", size=2) + theme_bw() +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="Comic Sans MS"))
```

This renders as:

[image]

*More on the subject e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522732/changing-fonts-in-ggplot2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675147/how-can-we-make-xkcd-style-graphs)*

---

I can also integrate that plot and extrafont into a shiny app which runs locally as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
library(shiny)

font_import(paths = "www", pattern = "comic", prompt = FALSE)
loadfonts()
print(fonts())

ui <- fluidPage(plotOutput("plot"),textOutput("fonts"))

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
     ggplot(mapping=aes(x=seq(1,10,.1), y=seq(1,10,.1))) + 
       geom_line(position="jitter", color="red", size=2) + theme_bw() +
       theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="Comic Sans MS"))
   })
   output$fonts <- renderText(print(fonts()))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

However, when I try to deploy this to shinyapps.io I get an error:

> The application failed to start (exited with code 1).
>
> Registering fonts with R Scanning ttf files in www ... Extracting .afm
>   files from .ttf files...
>   /srv/connect/apps/21-comic-font/www/comici.ttfWarnung in gzfile(dest,
>   "w")   kann komprimierte Datei
>   '/opt/R/3.4.3/lib/R/library/extrafontdb/metrics/comici.afm.gz' nicht
>   öffnen. Grund evtl. 'Permission denied' Fehler in value[3L] :
>   kann Verbindung nicht öffnen Ruft auf: local ... tryCatch ->
>   tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->  Ausführung angehalten

---

I tried to solve this by incorporating the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812219/using-custom-fonts-on-shinyapps-io#comment96844856_51812219). I added my `.ttf` files to the `www` directory and the `extrafontdb` package source to the `r-lib` directory. (And of course I deployed both..).

The complete `app.R` file now looks like:

```
.libPaths(c('r-lib', .libPaths()))
install.packages('r-lib/extrafontdb_1.0.tar.gz',type = 'source',repos = NULL)

library(ggplot2)
library(extrafontdb)
library(extrafont)
library(shiny)

font_import(paths = "www", pattern = "comic", prompt = FALSE)
loadfonts()
print(fonts())

ui <- fluidPage(plotOutput("plot"),textOutput("fonts"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mapping=aes(x=seq(1,10,.1), y=seq(1,10,.1))) +
      geom_line(position="jitter", color="red", size=2) + theme_bw() +
      theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="Comic Sans MS"))
  })
  output$fonts <- renderText(print(fonts()))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I deploy this I get a running app and the following output:

[image]

Now the strange thing is, that `renderText(print(fonts()))` prints *Comic Sans MS*. So it *seems* that my font got loaded. But the plot does not show the proper font.

Why is that? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work on `shinyapps.io` *(but not locally, since it is a Linux only solution. And somehow it did not work with my original 'ComicSans MS' font, but that font is not beautiful anyway.. ;-))*

Here we go:

1. Place custom font in `www` directory: e.g. `IndieFlower.ttf` from [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Indie+Flower)
2. Follow the steps from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/0czcsM4vziM)

This leads to the following `app.R` file:

```
ibrary(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

dir.create('~/.fonts')
file.copy("www/IndieFlower.ttf", "~/.fonts")
system('fc-cache -f ~/.fonts')

ui <- fluidPage(plotOutput("plot"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mapping=aes(x=seq(1,10,.1), y=seq(1,10,.1))) +
      geom_line(position="jitter", color="red", size=2) + theme_bw() +
      theme(text=element_text(size = 16, family = "IndieFlower"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The plot looks like:

[image]